# Можно ли в Eloquent модели (Laravel) сделать вычисляемое поле на основе данных другой модели?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Хотелось бы вычислять среднюю оценку пользователями публикации при обращении к ней.

Есть модели Laravel **User**, **Post**, (**UserPostVote** с pivot таблицей *user_post_score*).
В pivot таблице *user_post_score* 3 столбца: *user_id*, *post_id*, *score*. Пользователь голосует за публикацию и в *user_post_score* появляется запись связывающая его с публикацией и оценка в поле score.

В модели **Post** есть поле *score* (средняя оценка статьи пользователями) - вот его и хотелось бы вычислять, когда читается запись из таблицы.

Либо подскажите как можно решить это *другим способом*.

Конечно это можно сделать в контроллере, но у меня прописаны связи, например, для получения всех публикаций автора *$user->publications* и если все брать в контроллере тогда все плюшки от связей нивелируются. Возможно в методе связи пользователя с его публикациями publications просто выполнять подзапрос?

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{   
public function publications()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'id');
        }
}
```

Как неинтерактивное решение есть мысль  сделать сервис и дергать его раз в час по крону, что бы он рассчитывал рейтинг для каждой статьи и обновлял поле score. Но понимаю, что это велосипед.

**Решение**

Спасибо [n.osennij](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/19815/n-osennij) за [идею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094506/211339)!

Сделал так:

В модель **Post** добавил поле:

```
protected $appends = ['rate'];
```

И в ту же модель **Post** добавил метод:

```
public function getRateAttribute()
    {
        $post_votes = DB::table('user_post_vote')->where('post_id', $this->id)->select('score')->get()->pluck('score');
        if($post_votes->count() > 0) {
            return $post_votes->sum()/$post_votes->count();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Из view Blade шаблона вызываю расчет рейтинга для каждой публикации

```
<p>{{$post->rate}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так а в чём проблема? Создавайте метод любой в модели, делайте внутри, что хотите. И вызывайте его, где понадобится.

Или можно добавить в текущему перечню модели поле, которые будет всегда автоматически возвращатся с другими стандартными полями при запросе. В модели:

```
protected $appends = ['rate'];

public function getRateAttribute()
{
    return 76; // перед этим любая ваша логика.
}
```